# Como agregar filas y columnas a un DataGrid en Compact Framework 3.5

Tags: c#, datagrid, embebido

soy nuevo programando en C# y estoy realizando una aplicación para un dispositivo con Windows embedded 7 en la cual se usará un DataGrid pero no encuentro la forma para agregar datos y columnas, en el framework 3.5 si me funciona el siguiente código:

```
mydatagrid.Columns.Add("apellido", "Apellido");
```

Pero en el Compact No, como podré agregar filas y columnas?
Gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataGrid no es para manipular data, por lo que no podrá editar, eliminar, agregar directamente al control, por lo tanto tienes que utilizar una fuente de datos como un DataTable.

Para tu caso debes agregar la columna y los datos a tu fuente de datos.

Ejemplo:

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add("Nombre");
dataTable.Rows.Add("Feder");
dataGrid1.DataSource = dataTable;
```

Todo la manipulación de datos debes hacerlo en el DataTable, automáticamente se sincronizara con el control DataGrid.

Comment: Hasta donde yo se, el datagrid si permite agregar columnas y datos de forma manual. A qué DataGrid te refieres?